# Рандомное числа в двоичную систему рекурсией

Tags: javascript

Есть например цифра 578, как перевести в двоичную систему рекусрией? всмысле чтобы получилось 100101 или как там..
В интернете не нашел информацию

```js
  function bin(num){
        if(num){
            return x=(x/2)*2;
            bin()
        }
    }
    let x= +prompt();
    alert(bin(x));
```

Comment: «В интернете не нашел информацию» — Плохо искали) http://google.com/#q=Number+to+binary+algorithm

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME меня учили проще. Кто ищет тот бога найдет. Если не нашел то плохо искал

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вывести в консоль

```js
 console.log((578 >>> 0).toString(2));

function toBin(decimal){
   return decimal == 0 ? 0: (decimal % 2 + 10 * toBin(decimal/2|0))
}

console.log(toBin(578));
```

Если так уж хочется рекурсию посмотрите в такую сторону.

578 = 289*2

Вот что я имел ввиду. Обновил ответ

Comment: Пусто в консоле

Comment: А так что видать?

Comment: а можно это сделать рекурсией?

Comment: Интересно конечно. Можно думаю. Только через степень 2

Comment: дополнил вопрос, вроде бы должно работать но возвращает то же число

Comment: @Мнебезсахара, потому что Вы сначала поделили на 2, а потом умножили)) Т.е. умножили на 1 .

Comment: @entithat ну он так и писал) 578 = 289*2

Comment: а самому подумать? :)

Comment: @entithat тоесть двоичная система каждую цифру делит на 2?

Comment: Бинго вы выйграли

Comment: Последный вопрос :D. вопросительный знак это if а двоеточие это если?

Comment: Отве с рекурсивно уже есть. С телефона набрал.

Comment: @Мнебезсахара, да....

Comment: @OptimusPrime надо же назвать одинаково методы. Видать заставили они людей мыслить в одну сторону